# iPhone 4s navigation bar button item goes down when an actionsheet is presented

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image: iPhone 4s issue]

The application works perfectly fine with any other devices but iPhone 4s does this. I have used screen debugger and I can see its y position increases but I have no idea why.

Here is the code snippet, I call `configureNavigationBarWithTitle()` from `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
func configureNavigationBarWithTitle(title: String, shouldDisplayHomeButton: Bool = false) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = UIView.createNavigationTitleView(title: title)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.createAZBackButton(target: self)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(navigateBack(sender:))

    if shouldDisplayHomeButton {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.createAZHomeButton(target: self)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(navigateToRoot(sender:))
    }
}


extension UIBarButtonItem {
static func createAZBackButton(target: Any?) -> UIBarButtonItem {
    let img = UIImage(named: "back")
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .plain, target: target, action: nil)
    button.title = ""
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    button.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(0, for: .default)
    return button
}

static func createAZHomeButton(target: Any?) -> UIBarButtonItem {
    let img = UIImage(named: "home")
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .plain, target: target, action: nil)
    button.title = ""
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    button.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(0, for: .default)
    return button
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code which is used or something like XIB file to us, @Burak?

Comment: added some code